# Infinitesimal generator of smooth SDE

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

Suppose we have the SDE $dX_t = \mu_t dt + \sigma_t dS_t$ where $S_t$ is a.s. continuously differentiable. More precisely, I want to put $S_t = \sum_{i = 1}^N X_ib_i(t)$ where the $X_i$ are i.i.d standard normals, $N$ is geometric, and the $b_i$'s are in $C_c^\infty(\Bbb R)$. It follows that $X_t$ is also a.s. continuously differentiable and therefore has quadratic covariation $[X_t] = 0$. By Ito's lemma, we have
$$
df(X_t) = \nabla f(X_t)dX_t$$
showing that the infinitesimal generator of $X_t$ is $ \mu_t \cdot \nabla $. When $S_t$ is Brownian motion, the generator contains second order derivatives, but apparently the finite variation of $S_t$ seems to delete them for some reason. I strongly suspect that I am missing some nuance (perhaps there is some hypothesis regarding filtrations or adaptations that I am not checking), but if my claim is correct, is there some intuition explaining why we obtain a first-order operator rather than a second-order one? If I am incorrect, is there even a way to find the infinitesimal generator of $X_t$ or is the SDE ill-defined?

Comment: There is no problem here; the second order derivatives in the Brownian motion case are just because of the non-zero quadratic variation.

Comment: @user6247850 so the infinitesimal generator is $\mu_t\cdot\nabla$ for continuously differentiable $S_t$?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed directly from chain rule we get

$$\frac{df(x_{t})}{dt}=\nabla f(x_{t})\frac{dx_{t}}{dt}$$

(no Ito-formula needed here).  In terms of the SDE satisfied by $x_{t}$,it is actually just satisfies the following ODE

$$\dot{x}_{t}=\mu_{t}+\sigma_{t}\sum_{i = 1}^N X_i\dot{b}_i(t).$$

As mentioned in the comments, the Ito formula was developed to be able to do chain-rule but in the Taylor expansion in the proof an extra factor shows up with the quadratic variation. In fact, the Stratonovich calculus gives the exact same formula

$$df(x_{t})=\nabla f(x_{t})\circ dx_{t}$$

$$=\nabla f(x_{t})dx_{t}+\frac{1}{2}\nabla^{2} f(x_{t}) d[x]_{t}.$$